# Problems updating the miktex-misc file

Tags: miktex-update

I think I'm having problems with the miktex-misc file update. The updates page informs you of the status "to be repaired", and when I press "update now", after some time, the window "miktex console needs to be closed" is displayed.
I press the OK button, and the console closes. Then I open console again, press "Check for updates", and miktex-misc is there again... after all, was it updated or not?
thank you very much for your attention

Comment: you are not alone: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/855

Comment: Thanks Mr. Fischer

Comment: I'm Mrs. Fischer, and you should wait a day or so to give the files a chance to wander through the mirrors.

Comment: Sorry Mrs. Fischer, and thanks again.

Comment: It worked. Thanks again Mrs. Fischer